# Access/sql ifnull or none

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, iif

i am working with two columns. in one column (placement ward) there are some blanks. When there are blanks i want to pull the values in another column (all committs), when it is not blank i want to keep the value in placement ward column. I am working in Access.Also the values are i am suppose to be working on are "none" not null. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please post what you tried. If you made no attempt, start [researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) to find an implementation in Access and then ask a *specific* question involving your earnest attempt.

Comment: Add some code you tried...

Answer (score 1):

Use `IIf`:

```sql
Select 
    *, 
    IIf([placement ward] = 'none', [all committs], [placement ward]) As PlacementWard
From 
    YourTable
```

If not "none", then check for blanks:

```sql
Select 
    *, 
    IIf(Nz([placement ward]) = '', [all committs], [placement ward]) As PlacementWard
From 
    YourTable
```

Comment: Thank you. I messed up, some records  are blank and some are "none". It is not the "none" records i need to change, its the blank ones.

Comment: Thank you. I messed up, some records  are blank and some are "none". It is not the "none" records i need to change, its the blank ones.    IIf([Placement Address]![Ward] = 'none', [All Commitments]![Ward], [Placement Address]![Ward]). When I run this it changes the # of reuslts i get back.

Comment: OK, see edited answer, please.